# Is this a clog, or poor plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, shower, sink, drain, clog

Our basement washroom shower started overflowing. It happens when we use the sink for longer than 30 seconds and when we use the shower. It will over flow, then slowly drain. We have tried snaking from the sink and the shower drain but the snake pops up clean in the opposite drain(from sink to shower drain and vise versa) It never used to do this in the years past. Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your sewer line is clogged.  Call a plumber for this one, they have the long snake and the power to eat through things like tree roots.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be a stopped up vent. There should be a vent pipe in one of the shower walls running straight and emerging on the roof. If you can get up there, you could snake a water hose down into the vent, turn on the water and blast out any blockage.